# AWS SQS FIFO Queue: The queue should either have ContentBasedDeduplication enabled or MessageDeduplicationId provided explicitly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, aws-cli, amazon-sqs, fifo

When I try to add a message to my `FIFO SQS` using `AWS CLI` I get:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendMessage operation: The queue should either have ContentBasedDeduplication enabled or MessageDeduplicationId provided explicitly
```

**My Request:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/307125934878/myqueue.fifo --message-body "hello world" --region us-east-1 --message-group-id 3
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to provide `--message-deduplication-id` or enable `ContentBasedDeduplication` for your queue:

> You may provide a MessageDeduplicationId **explicitly**.
> If you aren't able to provide a MessageDeduplicationId and you **enable ContentBasedDeduplication** for your queue, Amazon SQS uses a SHA-256 hash to generate the MessageDeduplicationId using the body of the message (but not the attributes of the message).

The [deduplication ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html) is:

> the token used for deduplication of sent messages. If a message with a particular message deduplication ID is sent successfully, any messages sent with the same message deduplication ID are accepted successfully but aren't delivered during the **5-minute** deduplication interval.

For the existing queue, you can **enable** it in its `Configuration` options:

[image]